# Is there any way to have multiple seeds.rb files? Any kind of 'versioning' for seed data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

We need to add more seed data for some newly added tables to "version 100" of our rails project.

However, if we simply add it to the *seeds.rb* and re-run the `rake db:seed` command, it will of course Re-add the original seed data, duplicating it.

So if you've already added seed data to seeds.rb for, say, TableOne ...

**How can we incrementally add seed data for TableTwo and TableThree at later stages of development?**

I'd hoped I could simply create a NEW *seeds_two.rb* file and run `rake db:seeds_two` but that gave an error `Don't know how to build task 'db:seeds_two'`

So it looks like ONLY "seeds.rb" can be used.

**How do people maintain incremental additions to seed data?**

Comment: why do you can't just run `rake db:reset` to avoid duplications?

Comment: I generally seed data in the migration itself which adds the table. Although not ideal, but seems reasonable. I would would be interested to know what other rails coder do in the situation.

Comment: @nash - doesnt db:reset wipe our dbase -- eg, all our existing real-life customer data?

Comment: @rubish that's okay except we often add more seed data over time, after the migration has been run. we could add new migrations, but I understood the db:seed was the "right" way to handle seed data, only I question that now if there is no versioning ability!

Comment: @jpwynn, I see. You can try seed-fu - https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can re-use the `seed` task, but make it [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning).

To make the seed idempotent, simply check for the existence of the condition before executing a command. An example: do you want to create a new admin user?

```
User.find_or_create_by_username(:username => "admin")
```

instead of

```
User.create(:username => "admin")
```

However, `seed` should be used to populate your database when the project is created. If you want to perform complex data seeding durin the lifecycle of the app, simply create a new rake task, execute it then remove it.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Plus I learned a cool new word I can use at parties ("I wish the calories in a hot fudge sundae were idempotent") ;) But I do have a question... how do you handle the case where as your project evolves, you add new fields and therefore need new seed data to go into those new fields? Rake? or Seed?

Comment: If I need more seed data to cover new models, I use the seed.rb file. If I just need to populate or alter the data in the production environment, I create temporary rake tasks.

Answer (score 18):

For those who have concerns about this question

We can have multiple seed files in `db/seeds/` folder, and, we can write a rake task to run the separate files as we desire to run

```
# lib/tasks/custom_seed.rake

namespace :db do
  namespace :seed do

    Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].each do |filename|
      task_name = File.basename(filename, '.rb').intern

      # Now we will create multiple tasks by each file name inside db/seeds directory. 

      task task_name => :environment do
        load(filename)
      end
    end

    # This is for if you want to run all seeds inside db/seeds directory
    task :all => :environment do
      Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].sort.each do |filename|
        load(filename)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Then, in order to run specific seed file, you can just run

```
rake db:seed:seed_file_name
```

To run all the seeds file with order in that `db/seeds` folder, run below command

```
rake db:seed:all
```

Comment: Makes more sense and includes both answers asked in the question. This answer should be a green tick.